# Storing query results from EXECUTE in a view - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, execute

I am trying to store the output of the following query into a view or a temporary table. I know that view requires the `SELECT` statement but I was wondering if it could work as well with the `EXECUTE` command.

This is my query:

```
SET @por= NULL;
SELECT

CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name)
SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'
), '\r\nUNION\r\n', 'select * from table1')

INTO
@union_por_tables
FROM
information_schema.tables
WHERE
table_schema = 'schema' AND table_name LIKE '%por%';

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @union_por_tables; 
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1
```

This query return me 250000 rows and I want to store them. Can someone help me?

Comment: Views don't store data.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is referred to as **materialized view**

From what I know at the moment, MySQL doesn't support materialized views. You can simulate it by inserting data in an actual table, thus maintaining the cache manually.

MariaDB implements materialized views via something they refer to as flexviews. The docs are here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flexviews/

You might explore the option of trying out MariaDB and its flexviews feature for your particular use case.